# How to remove element from an array in mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I have the following Schema:

```
// userSchema
{
  _id: Schema.ObjectId,
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
  boxes: [boxSchema]
}
// boxSchema
{
  _id: Schema.ObjectId,
  boxId: { type: String, unique: true },
  boxName: String
}
```

I have data like this:

```
{
 _id: random,
 email: em@i.l,
 password: hash,
 boxes: [{ "boxId" : "box1", "boxName" : "Box 1"}, 
  { "boxId" : "box2","boxName" : "Box 2"},
  { "boxId" : "box3","boxName" : "Box 3"}]
}
```

I am trying to remove an element from boxes array with boxId: box1 and the code I tried was this:

```
User.findOne({
        _id: req.body.id
    })
    .then(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            for (i in user.boxes)
                if (user.boxes[i].boxId === 'box1')
                   user.boxes[i].remove();
            res.json('removed');
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        ....
    });
```

But what happens is that it removes all the boxes which is residing, instead of the boxId: box1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `filter`

```
User.findOne({
    _id: req.body.id
})
.then(function (user) {
    if (user) {

        user.boxes = user.boxes.filter(function(box){
            return box.boxId !== 'box1'
        })

        res.json('removed');
     }
 })
.catch(function (err) {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to remove element from the array and are as follows:

1) Delete(): using this function will remove the element but will not change the array size and keep blank object after removal of element.

2)splice(): It works similar to delete() but remove blank places in array after removal of element.

3)filter(): It takes function as an argument and removes the element efficiently.